# Source for dying upon reaching a set number of words spoken

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, shiurim-measurements, speech-talking

If I recall correctly, it says somewhere that we each have a predefined number of words to speak, after which we die. (The idea being that one should be careful not to speak unnecessarily.)

Assuming my memory is correct, what is the source?

Comment: Maybe we should all start speaking [Newspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak)

Comment: @DoubleAA or maybe [German or Mongolian](http://www.ravi.io/language-word-lengths)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses If you really want to go there: Wordlength isn't directly relevant. (It wouldn't save you anything to speak a language identical to English, but with every letter doubled, though it would score 16.46.) You would have to compare number of words in translated texts. I suppose the predefined number works like a currency. In a language that uses 50% more words, you would have 150% as many words to speak in your lifetime...